# idapython: getting a list of all segments

Tags: ida, idapython

If I open the Segments subview in IDA, I can get a list of all of the segments.

I would like to access this list so I can enumerate through all of the segments.

How can I do this with idapython?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use the `Segments()` from [idautils](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/).

```
from idautils import *
from idc import *
from idaapi import *

for ea in Segments():
    print '%x-%x'%(SegStart(ea),SegEnd(ea))
```